# Ampersand and nesting SASS

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I'd just like to know the difference, when using Sass, between simple nesting

```
p{
   color: white;

    .text{
         text-decoration: underline;
     }
```

}

and nesting using an Ampersand '&'

```
p{
    color: white;

    &.text{
          text-decoration: underline;
     }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example without the ampersand will select every child of a p element with the class text. The example with the ampersand will select every p element with the class text. With your code, using the first selector will make every p element with a child that has the text class have an underline. However, the second selector will make every p element with the text class underlined.

Answer (score 1):

As per your questions:

1.

```css
p {
    color: white;
    .text {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

It indicates: CSS properties output to all the `.text` class selector inside `p` tag. Like `p .text{}`

2.

```css
p{
    color: white;
    
    &.text{
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}
```

It indicates: When you use `&` with `.text` selector the CSS properties output to all the `.text` class selectors within `p` tag. Like `p.text{}`

Good luck buddy!

Comment: I think I understand, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

In the first one the `.text` has to be a child element of `p` (in CSS that would be `p .text {...}`) , in the second one the `.text` rule applies to all `p` tags that have the `text` class (i.e. `p.text {...}`)